# Germ of regulars functions vs formal functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Given a ring $R$ and a prime ideal $P ⊂ R$, one can either consider the ring of germs of functions at $P$, which is the colimit (union) $\varinjlim R[\frac{1}{f}]$, over all $f\not\in P$; this is the stalk of the sheaf of regular functions at $P$.
One can also take the ring of formal functions at $P$, which is the inverse limit $\varprojlim R/P^k$, i.e. completion with respect to the ideal $P$.

My understanding is that the formal neighborhood of $P$ is given by the formal scheme which is the inverse limit $\varinjlim \operatorname{Spec} R/{P^k}$, which is an Ind-object of the category of schemes.

I have two questions.

1. Why don't we just consider the usual scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(\varprojlim R/{P^k})$ as the formal neighborhood of $P \in \operatorname{Spec} R$?
2. Why do we never consider $\operatorname{Spec}$ of the ring of germs of functions at $P$, i.e.
   $\varprojlim \operatorname{Spec} R[ 1/f]$ or $\operatorname{Spec}( \varinjlim R[ 1/f])$, as a formal neighborhood of $P$?

Basically question 2 is why do we use formal functions and not germs of functions to represent formal neighborhoods?

Comment: For the first question you might find this (and the other) answer helpful https://mathoverflow.net/a/319117/132180